# Google drive API doesn't accept & encoded and unencoded

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I built an application in PHP which uses gdrive sdk to do the following query for a tile containing certain keywords.  As of 9-17-2014, accord to error logs, the api does not return files if the title im querying for has an "&" ( or encoded %26) .
I tested this using  https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

I authenticated and ran the following call:

https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?maxResults=2&q=title+contains+%27Referral+%27

Returned 2 files as expected. The full file name is "Referral & UUs".

if i try the original query, which worked prior to 9-17-2014

https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?maxResults=2&q=title+contains+%27Referral+%26%27

Returns nothing....

Does the Google Drive not accept ampersands anymore ?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in the Files.list() endpoint, and I've raised the issue internally. At least for now, you can work around the problem by requesting the scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata" in addition to the other scopes you are requesting.